Differentiate Equal USB Devices
I have the following problem. Im developing an embedded system and I have two USB to UART devices (FT232). The problem is that I need to differentiate them because sometimes when booting one shows up as /dev/TTYUSB0 and others as /dev/TTYUSB1.
If I use libusb to read their info its exactly the same:
Bus 003 Device 028 ID 0403:6001 DeviceDescriptor { bLength: 18, bDescriptorType: 1, bcdUSB: 512, bDeviceClass: 0, bDeviceSubClass: 0, bDeviceProtocol: 0, bMaxPacketSize: 8, idVendor: 1027, idProduct: 24577, bcdDevice: 1536, iManufacturer: 1, iProduct: 2, iSerialNumber: 3, bNumConfigurations: 1 }

Bus 003 Device 027 ID 0403:6001 DeviceDescriptor { bLength: 18, bDescriptorType: 1, bcdUSB: 512, bDeviceClass: 0, bDeviceSubClass: 0, bDeviceProtocol: 0, bMaxPacketSize: 8, idVendor: 1027, idProduct: 24577, bcdDevice: 1536, iManufacturer: 1, iProduct: 2, iSerialNumber: 3, bNumConfigurations: 1 }

The only difference is that one is plugged to a different physical port in the hub, but as far as I know its impossible to access / talk the actual Hub to see what is connected where.
The only solution would be to talk to the hub (if its even possible) and see what tty is assigned to a device on an specific physical socket?
Thanks!

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_124_User_Guide_For_FT_PROG.pdf

The fact that both were produced with the same SerialNumber interface property makes this extra annoying. The genuine FT232 comes pre-programmed with unique serial numbers, so you have a fake chip on your hand. Might be nice to know.
Anyways, you can of course look at which port on a hub holds which device: under /sys/bus/usb/devices/ you'll find the USB-connected devices described as
{number of root bus}-{Port on root hub}[.{port on next-layer hub}[.{port on next-layer hub}]…]

So, /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9.2.1 is the USB device connected to the first USB root controller I have, there on the 9. port, to which a hub is connected, and there on the second port, there's a hub connected, and on the first port of that, there's my mouse.
On /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9.1 I have a serial adapter. When I look into that directory, I find another directory, 1-9.1:1.0, and in that a directory another directory ttyUSB0. in `ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0/device, I finally find the link to /dev/ttyUSB0. So, if you wanted to write your own tooling, that's how you find out what belongs to which port.
HOWEVER. You shouldn't write your own tooling. This is what udev is for! Learn how to install your own udev rules, and add one, roughly like this:
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" ATTRS{devpath}=="9.1:1.0" SYMLINK+="serial0"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" ATTRS{devpath}=="9.2:1.0" SYMLINK+="serial1"

adjusting port numbers and devpath as appropriate for your specific devices, and your connections. This will give you two symlinks that you should use instead of /dev/ttyUSB0: /dev/serial0, and /dev/serial1

Solved! With regards to the serial num, i think it was the way i extracted them, using usb-devices does show proper serial nums. I checked the documentation of libusb and there is a way to get the actual "ports" in which devices are connected to the hubs, I might just use this.
